# SAPUi5 TypeError: I.fFunction.call is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5, typeerror, function-call

I'm implementing a FileUploader, displayed in a Dialog. Relevant Code:

```
function onAddExcelData() {
    var that = this;
    if(this.fixedDialog === undefined) {
        this.fixedDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
            title: "Choose CSV File for Upload",
            beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Upload",
                press: function(oEvent) {
                    that.fixedDialog.close();
                }
            }),  
            content: [
                new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader("excelUploader")
            ],
            endButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: "Cancel",
                press: function() {
                    that.fixedDialog.close();
                }
            })
        })
       this.getView().addDependent(this.fixedDialog);
       this.fixedDialog.attachBeforeClose(this.setDataToJsonFromExcel, this);
   }

   this.fixedDialog.open();
}
```

Whenever I want to click the beginButton or endButton, the console shows the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: I.fFunction.call is not a function
```

I read about this issue and the suggested solution is always, to define a new variable before calling the press function. But even though I added that variable, I still get the error. Does anyone have further ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with this line. I don't know what it does so I can't comment further on this issue. The functions work just fine without it. Are you sure function `setDataToJsonFromExcel` exists in your controller?

Hope this helps.

```
this.fixedDialog.attachBeforeClose(this.setDataToJsonFromExcel, this);
```